# Setting up php_mapscript in portable GIS

Tags: open-source-gis, web-mapping, mapserver

I'm new here, and I'm also new in webgis, I have downloaded portable
gis. I have a question regarding to mapserver that comes with portable GIS v2, how to set up or add php_mapscript extension to php in xampplite, I have
tried to do it like this but failed:

1. Add the necessary files (libmap.dll, gdal17.dll, etc.)  to a new
   folder (foldername = A ). I get those files from new version of MS4W.
2. Add the folder path to the windows path environment.
3. Modified php.ini to add php_mapscript

When I try to launch apache server it says something like "couldn't
load msvcr90.dll", I copied the file from windows folder and added it to
folder A, new error says "wrong msvcr version".

Can anyone help me, so I can use php_mapscript extension.

Answer (score 1):

A fix for this is to edit your **php.ini** file and ensure that you are
loading these two extensions.

extension=php_msvcr90.dll

extension=gdal17.dll

to check try this code:

```
<?php  dl("php_mapscript.so");
       phpinfo();
?>
```

However
Note: **When setting up PHP on Windows, make sure that PHP is configured as a CGI and not as an Apache module because php_mapscript.dll is not thread-safe and does not work as an Apache module**

more info:
http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/PHPMapScriptCGI

Comment: where i can find php_msvcr90.dll? i've search and can't find any, googling too... you're right,in httpd.conf php was setup as an apache module maybe this could cause the problem too.

Comment: try your 'msvcr90.dll' file extension=msvcr90.dll